Merge rows of data frame that satisfy condition (belong to a group) by column (id)
I've got a 300x5 data frame that looks like this (3 groups, 100 rows per group, ids go from 01 to 100 per group, same id means same feat2 and feat3 but always different num_to_sum):



factor/group
id
num_to_sum
feat2
feat3




group1
01
4
...
...


group1
02
9
...
...


group2
01
3
...
...


group2
02
1
...
...


group3
01
4
...
...


group3
02
8
...
...



Now, I'd like to merge all rows by id but only if they belong to a certain group. For example: I want to merge group1 and group2 by id and apply the sum operator to num_to_sum, so the final data frame (output) shall look like this:



factor/group
id
summed_num
feat2
feat3




group12
01
(4+3=)7
...
...


group12
02
(9+1=)10
...
...


group3
01
4
...
...


group3
02
8
...
...



I don't mind about the other features (feat2 and feat3); they are actually the same for each id regardless of the group, so I could drop them, I just don't want them duplicated in the final df as that would mean duplicated data and that's messy.
It'd be great if there is a solution that can be applied to not just two groups, but to n groups that shall be merged.
I've looked at stats::aggregate, but I can't figure out how to aggregate with a condition.

Do you want the actual sum as a string in summed_num?  That is , do you want summed_sum to contain "(4+3=)7" etc or 7 etc?   Also, do you want to coallesce the values of factor/group?  Please post both your desired input and output using dput.

@Limey I‘d like the plain numbers as output, not the string, I put that for clarification (so just 7 etc.). Yes, I want to create a new group with a new name from group1 and group2, it does not have to be „group12“, I want to choose it freely. I‘ll update my question.

You should create a new factor that combines the groups you want to sum,
then aggregate with that and the id.
With base R:
tab <- read.table(text = "
factor/group    id  num_to_sum
group1  01  4
group1  02  9
group2  01  3
group2  02  1
group3  01  4
group3  02  8
", header = TRUE)

tab
#>   factor.group id num_to_sum
#> 1       group1  1          4
#> 2       group1  2          9
#> 3       group2  1          3
#> 4       group2  2          1
#> 5       group3  1          4
#> 6       group3  2          8

grp <- factor(tab$factor.group)
levels(grp) <- list(group12 = c("group1", "group2"), group3 = "group3")
grp
#> [1] group12 group12 group12 group12 group3  group3 
#> Levels: group12 group3

aggregate(num_to_sum ~ id + grp, tab, sum)
#>   id     grp num_to_sum
#> 1  1 group12          7
#> 2  2 group12         10
#> 3  1  group3          4
#> 4  2  group3          8

With forcats and dplyr:
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(forcats)

tab |>
  mutate(grp = fct_collapse(factor.group, group12 = c("group1", "group2"))) |>
  group_by(grp, id) |>
  summarise(num_to_sum = sum(num_to_sum))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'grp'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   grp [2]
#>   grp        id num_to_sum
#>   <fct>   <int>      <int>
#> 1 group12     1          7
#> 2 group12     2         10
#> 3 group3      1          4
#> 4 group3      2          8


I like your first one in base R best because it's quite clear to me  – wasn't sure which answer to pick because I like them all, but personally this one was the most intuitive approach.

Using dplyr, doing this in two steps:
summarise(filter(df, group %in% c("group1", "group2")) |>
            mutate(group="group12"),
          summed_num=sum(num_to_sum),
          .by=c(group, id)) |>
  bind_rows(filter(df, !group %in% c("group1", "group2")) |>
              rename(summed_num=num_to_sum))


  group      id summed_num
  <chr>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 group12     1          7
2 group12     2         10
3 group3      1          4
4 group3      2          8


df <- structure(list(group = c("group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", 
"group3", "group3"), id = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), num_to_sum = c(4, 
9, 3, 1, 4, 8)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))


Here is a long dplyr pipe but I think readable.
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
})

bind_rows(
  df1 %>%
    filter(group %in% c("group1", "group2")) %>%
    summarise(
      group = paste(group, collapse = ", "),
      summed_num = sum(num_to_sum), 
      feat2 = paste(feat2, collapse = ", "),
      feat3 = paste(feat3, collapse = ", "),
      .by= id
    ),
  df1 %>%
    filter(!group %in% c("group1", "group2")) %>%
    rename(summed_num = num_to_sum)
)
#>   id          group summed_num    feat2    feat3
#> 1  1 group1, group2          7 ..., ... ..., ...
#> 2  2 group1, group2         10 ..., ... ..., ...
#> 3  1         group3          4      ...      ...
#> 4  2         group3          8      ...      ...

Created on 2024-07-05 with reprex v2.1.0

Data
df1 <- "group   id  num_to_sum  feat2   feat3
group1  01  4   ...     ...
group1  02  9   ...     ...
group2  01  3   ...     ...
group2  02  1   ...     ...
group3  01  4   ...     ...
group3  02  8   ...     ..."
df1 <- read.table(text = df1, header = TRUE)


Using by.
> by(df, df$factor.group %in% paste0('group', 1:2), aggregate, num_to_sum ~ id, sum)
df$factor.group %in% paste0("group", 1:2): FALSE
  id num_to_sum
1  1          4
2  2          8
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$factor.group %in% paste0("group", 1:2): TRUE
  id num_to_sum
1  1          7
2  2         10

Or aggregate with a slightly transformed data frame.
> df |> 
+   transform(group=c('group12', 'group3')[
+     factor.group %in% paste0('group', 1:2) + 1L
+   ]) |> 
+   aggregate(num_to_sum ~ group + id, sum)
    group id num_to_sum
1 group12  1          4
2  group3  1          7
3 group12  2          8
4  group3  2         10


Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(factor.group = c("group1", "group1", "group2", 
"group2", "group3", "group3"), id = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
    num_to_sum = c(4L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 8L), feat2 = c("...", 
    "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."), feat3 = c("...", "...", 
    "...", "...", "...", "...")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

